# Embedded report on form asking for ID parameter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm making **a form in Access that contains an embedded report**. This report is made to be a matrix, and changes based on the value the user inputs (i.e. user enters 5, it's now a 5x5 matrix, etc).

Everything is working correctly and as intended. However, no matter what accepted value is entered (with the exception of the default value of 10, which requires no changes to the report), it always asks for a parameter value for `"tRAM10x10.ID"`, **tRAM10x10 being the name of the table that the report was created from.** Regardless of what is given for the value, nothing changes. Simply hitting okay without entering anything works, entering 0 works, etc., and nothing changes to reflect the entered value.

Normally I would just give it a value somewhere in the code, but everything I've tried doesn't work. I also can't find anything related to Access asking for a parameter like this online.

The `.ID` in the parameter name gets in the way of statements like `Me.reportname.etc`

The "ID" field in the related table is displayed on the report and showing all the correct values, with no changes when something is entered for the parameter value.

This is the part of the code that edits the report if the user wants the report to be a 5x5 matrix. All the parts that edit the report are the same as this, give or take a few statements.

```
'Set sources to textboxes that won't have a source when using a 5x5 RAM
Me.rRAM10x10.Report.tBox6.ControlSource = "blank"
Me.rRAM10x10.Report.tBox7.ControlSource = "blank"
Me.rRAM10x10.Report.tBox8.ControlSource = "blank"
Me.rRAM10x10.Report.tBox9.ControlSource = "blank"
Me.rRAM10x10.Report.tBox10.ControlSource = "blank"

'changes the report properties to read the appropriate table for a 5x5 RAM
Me.rRAM10x10.Report.RecordSource = "tRAM5x5"
```

I hope I explained that clearly, let me know if anything needs clarified.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: So does a textbox have a ControlSource of `tRAM10x10.ID`?

Comment: I think we need to see the table definition. What is ID?

Comment: And why would you need a different table for each size matrix? Bet this could be accomplished with a single table.

Comment: Okay so one at a time, @dbmitch yes it compiles. Keep in mind this isn't all the code, just a snippet that changes size of the report. The code is 100% working, I'm just trying to get rid of this prompt.


@June7 No, there are no textboxes that have `tRAM10x10.ID` as a control source. Some use "ID" as a control source, but they're receiving values just fine. I don't want to get into why each size matrix has its own table, maybe you're right, but its not relevant right now. 

@nicomp ID is the primary key of the table.

Comment: Check your grouping and sorting - if there's no textbox on your report by that name it might be leftover in there.Also I thought the reportt was based on one table - what do you mean when you say `"ID" field in the related table is displayed`

Comment: @dbmitch I checked, and there are no issues in grouping and sorting. The report is based off one table "tRAM10x10" but the control source is changed to other tables for different matrix sizes (i.e. tRAM5x5 is set as the control source if the user wants a 5x5 matrix). If there would be a better way of doing this, I can try changing it in the future, but for now I'm kinda stuck as is.

Comment: Are the other 'table' recordsources like `tRAM5x5` actually tables - or are they queries?

Comment: Ahhh - I think I know what the issue is - reading your first line gives a clue, though you never mention it specifically `a form in Access that contains an embedded report` - doesn't that mean you've linked the form to the report with a parent/child relationship? It's likely you've set that up with `tRAM10x10.ID` as the child field